# How to delete a list of git branches locally?

Tags: git

I have a list of git branches locally which I need to get rid of.
I have been doing

```
git branch -d name-of-branch
```

but it only deletes one branch at a time. I do have about a hundred of them.

Thanks

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow for at least 5-10 minutes before posting a question.